# Openpyxl saving a corrupted/ not readable file. No error report, just shell restart

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I've been learning Python for several months now to automate some boring tasks at work (mostly Excel) and I've succeeded in most cases. But for two weeks now I've been trying to solve a problem that I encountered with openpyxl while populating a weekly report with data gathered from other spreadsheets.
The openpyxl version is 3.0.2 according to `openpyxl.__version__` and I'm using Python 3.6.7 with built-in IDLE.
EDIT: here's full code https://pastebin.com/MrBZ5Usu.

What the program is supposed to do is:

1. Gather the data from week's worth of reports and put that in a list
2. Gather data from spreadsheet with dates as keys and hours as values of a dict
3. Open a template spreadsheet, populate it with this data and save it as another file.

Now when I run the program I get no error report. The Python shell restarts. The file is there, but it's 0 bytes and impossible to open.
I've run some tests and up until the moment of saving the workbook everything seems fine. When called, the cells in the new workbook show the values that I put in them. Every piece of data is in wished, standardized format/type.
When I call the `wb.save(filename)` method, the shell restarts. 
I've tried different ways to put the data into the cells (looping with f-strings, looping with predefined list of cell coords, hardcoding the cells and data) but to no avail. Shell restart - 0 bytes spreadsheet. 
I've made sure that every module on my machine is up do date etc.
I've succeeded in writing the data to a shelve module and then extracting them with another script. 
The second script (just several lines, with same pieces of code for filling out the cells) succeeded in saving a valid workbook, but only if it was the same file. 
I've tried changing that in the main program, but no save option (as different file, as same file, a shutil copy of the file(!)) granted success. 
There's obviously something wrong with my code (except for all the newbie's mistakes) but I cannot put my hand on it. Here's the code - does anyone have any suggestions? On request I may provide basically whole script (around 120 lines).

```
endlist = load_workbook(f"Endlist_{monat1}_2019.xlsx", data_only=True)
endlistws = endlist.active


#creating an empty dict, to store the dates and hours from endlist
endlist_hrs = {}

#creating a dict with dates as keys and empty lists as values
for cell in endlistws['A']:
    if cell.value != None:
        if weeknum(dateConverter(cell.value)) == kw_num:
            if dateConverter(endlistws[f'A{cell.row}'].value) in endlist_hrs.keys(): #is the date already in the dict?
                pass # it is, so pass
            else:
                endlist_hrs[dateConverter((endlistws[f'A{cell.row}'].value))] = [] #its not, so add it
    else:
        pass #does not match

# iterating over keys in the endlist_hrs dict, checking the dates in A column - not the best solution, iterating every time over whole A column - to be upgraded
for key in endlist_hrs.keys():
    for cell in endlistws['A']:
        if cell.value != None:
            if dateConverter(cell.value) == key:
                endlist_hrs[key].append(czasownik(endlistws[f'J{cell.row}'].value))


endlist.close() #closing the endlist workbook

#creating a dict with dates as keys and sum of hours as values - ready to be inserted into cells in the Check workbook
full_endlist_data = {k:sum(v) for (k,v) in endlist_hrs.items()}

#copying the dailycheck workbook and producing the final output

faylneym = f"DC{kw_num}.xlsx"
paf = os.path.join(values['Browse0'], faylneym)

shutil.copy2(values['Browse1'], paf)

dcwb = load_workbook(paf, write_only=True)
dcws = dcwb['KW_XX']
dcws.title = str(kw)
dcwb.save(paf)
dcwb = load_workbook(paf)
dcws = dcwb.active

for x,y in enumerate(strdate, start=2):
    dcws[f'A{x}'].value = y
for x,y in enumerate(strdate, start=12):
    dcws[f'A{x}'].value = y
for x,y in enumerate(hours_from_eos2, start=2):
    dcws[f'E{x}'].value = y
for x,y in enumerate(full_endlist_data.values(), start=2):
    dcws[f'D{x}'].value = y
```

After that I'm just saving the workbook.

Comment: print(openpyxl.__version__)
3.0.2

Comment: File an issue at [bitbucket.org/openpyxl](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl) if you think it's a bug.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Please simplify it.

Comment: After filling cells in a workbook with data and trying to save it - the python shell restarts. File exists, but its empty (0 bytes). Up to saving point everything works as it should.

Comment: What do you mean "the Python shell restarts"?

Comment: When I'm running my script in IDLE, usually after successfully executed script Python prints out just three "arrows" ">>>" . After executing the faulty script I get the full ========RESTART======= line, as if I pressed "Restart Shell" (ctrl+F6). No modules imported, to output data etc.

Comment: Sounds like Python is crashing for some reason. Try running it from the command line to see if you can get an exception. You'll probably have to start a separate question if it's just a crash.

Answer (score 0):

I've rebuilt my code have some more functional than structural character. I've also split the filling out section of code to 4 functions.

1. Copying the spreadsheet and giving it a new name.
2. Opening the spreadsheet and filling it out with previously generated list(6 items, a range of dates in given WK) then saving the workbook.
3. Opening the workbook, iterating through a list of 6 items and putting them into their places. Saving the workbook.
4. Opening the workbook, iterating through dict values and putting them into planned cells. Saving the workbook.

Doing it this way I encounter no errors, crashes or unexpected behavior. Workbook is populated with data as intended and error-free. Unfortunately I'm not advanced enough to pinpoint the exact cause.
Here's the final code:

```
def newWB(source, target, kw_num):
    faylneym = f"DC{kw_num}.xlsx"
    paf = os.path.join(target, faylneym)
    shutil.copy2(source, paf)
    return paf



def filling1(wbpaf, strdata):
    try:
        dcwb = load_workbook(wbpaf)
        dcws = dcwb.active

        for x, y in enumerate(strdate, start=2):
            dcws[f'A{x}'].value = y
        for x, y in enumerate(strdate, start=12):
             dcws[f'A{x}'].value = y
        # for x, y in enumerate(hours_from_eos, start=2):
        #     dcws[f'E{x}'].value = y
        # for x, y in enumerate(endlist_hrs.values(), start=2):
        #     dcws[f'D{x}'].value = y
        dcwb.save(wbpaf)

    except:
        sg.Popup("Filling1 with data failed")

def filling2(wbpaf, hours_from_eos):
    try:
        dcwb = load_workbook(wbpaf)
        dcws = dcwb.active
        for x, y in enumerate(hours_from_eos, start=2):
            dcws[f'E{x}'].value = y
        dcwb.save(wbpaf)
    except:
        sg.Popup("Filling2 with data failed")

def filling3(wbpaf, endlist_hrs):
    try:
        dcwb = load_workbook(wbpaf)
        dcws = dcwb.active
        for x, y in enumerate(endlist_hrs.values(), start=2):
            dcws[f'D{x}'].value = y
        dcwb.save(wbaf)
    except:
        sg.Popup("Filling3 failed")'
```